# TextInput selectionColor property no changing color on android

Tags: android, react-native, textinput

After reading the React Native documentation I understood that selectionColor was used to change the color of the cursor instead of that primary default color of android system.

So I tried the following:

```
<TextInput selectionColor="#2E5BFF" {...props} autoCapitalize="none" autoCorrect={false} />
```

The problem is that on android devices it still gets that green default color of android, on the emulator tought its fine and is showing `#2E5BFF` color. My android devices both have android P.

Is there any known bug or am I doing something wrong here?

**EDIT**

I'm using Expo SDK 32.0.0

Comment: <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/darkred</item> not sure if styles are available in react or if this is handled in another way, but if they are you can try these attributes in your style

Answer (score 4):

You can set `colorControlActivated` in `styles.xml` file.Like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/kio_turquoise</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/kio_hot_pink</item>

    <!-- sets cursor color -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/black</item>
 </style>
```

because the backbone of the app is the native android application. For more information you can refer this article. It is very helpful.

> [React native on android styling the cursor](http://www.kiodev.com/react-native-on-android-styling-the-cursor/)

Comment: Not applicable to Expo.

Answer (score -2):

```
    <TextInput 
   selectionColor={global.COLOR.DARKBLUE}
   underlineColorAndroid={global.COLOR.ORANGE}
  autoCapitalize="none" autoCorrect={false} />
```

you can try this